# Topicality of "DevOps" Questions

Tags: discussion, scope

[This question at Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/628156/how-do-you-manage-development-tasks-when-setting-up-your-development-environment) and the corresponding discussion got me thinking. There is already a [DevOps proposal on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97295/devops):

[image]

But in the interim (and frankly I don't know that we need a separate Stack Exchange site for DevOps), what is the guidance on the topicality of DevOps questions on Stack Overflow (or Server Fault for that matter, although this is not meta.SF)? Are questions related to operational concerns, but enabling development activities, on topic (for example, relating to technologies like Docker, [CI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration)/[CD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_delivery) pipelines, etc.)?

Comment: They should be on topic for SU or SF, in the same way that IT administration of workstations for healthcare professionals, or drafters, or anyone else are on-topic there (SU - administration of individual computers; SF - administration en masse).

Comment: @BenVoigt That may be clear in the case of basic workstation administration, but when dealing with technologies like Docker, CI/CD platforms, etc that are operational but may be intimately tied to development, it can be less obvious.

Comment: Please realize that your SF question got closed by a single user.  Try rewording it a little to focus on the "I have a set of applications that I'm trying to make portable" and de-emphasize that these apps happen to be development tools.

Comment: @BenVoigt Please note that the linked question was not written by me.  This is not a question about that question specifically, that is just context for the topic coming up.  I am interested in the community's feeling on adjudicating topicality as these questions are becoming more common.  I do actually agree with the thrust of your point though, so it might make a good answer in that the reality is that these are not necessarily development-specific but can be better generalized and thus made on topic for a particular site.  That would be a good answer.

Comment: oops, sorry about assuming you were the author of that question.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I closed that question, so perhaps I should weigh in here.

First, there's the term "DevOps". This, as I understand it from reading *The Phoenix Project* and paying attention to Gene Kim et al., is breaking down the artificial barriers between development and operations, and having them work closely together throughout the lifecycle of a project/product. Wherever possible this is to be commended and encouraged.

There's a second, much darker definition of "DevOps", which has very little to do with this. In this parallel universe, Ops is dispensed with altogether, and replaced with Dev. In other words, Dev does Ops. Unfortunately, since Dev and Ops require different skillsets without much overlap between them, a fact not widely recognized either by developers or management, this doesn't usually work out very well. It generally only seems to work when Dev *outsources* Ops, e.g. to AWS, Heroku, OpenShift, or some other public IT service, though this activity is closer to the first definition than the second.

So much for DevOps.

---

Here is the topic boundary for Server Fault:

While DevOps (done right) does blur the lines somewhat between Dev and Ops, there is still almost always a boundary where on one side is "operations" tasks, such as provisioning bare metal, backing up servers, configuration management, and so on, and on the other side is "development" tasks, such as configuring Jenkins to build a project automatically from a source code repository.

In the middle are tasks which aren't obviously on one side or the other, such as installing Jenkins and configuring the web server in front of it (which may be optional), setting up git, and so on. In some houses Dev does these tasks, while in others Ops does them. In these cases I try to give the benefit of the doubt.

---

With regard to this specific question, it asked for best practices for setting up a *development* environment for running Docker containers. That it was posted on Server Fault at all is surprising; it's obviously off topic there, much as a question about best practices for setting up Visual Studio would be.

Should SO accept questions about development tools and environments? If it is not already doing so, as specified in its own topic list, then it should be.

The specific question closed here is almost certainly too broad or opinion-based for SO, but might be suitable for Programmers (possibly after some editing). But in general, questions about setting up development workstations and environments should not be sent to Server Fault unless they are very obviously Ops tasks.

(And note that it's still OK for sites to have some topic overlap.)

Comment: Agreed re: the example question and its location on ServerFault, as asked it is not appropriate.  I also agree that SO is a sensible place for this stuff to sit unless/until it ends up in its own silo (which as you say is not entirely necessary, there can be overlap).  I also especially appreciate the reference to giving the benefit of the doubt to questions that fall on the real "line" between dev and ops, the lines are not bright enough for outright rejection, especially given the topicality statement in the SO FAQ.

Comment: Michael, I don't use Docker so perhaps I'm misunderstanding and correct me if I'm wrong, but that sounds a lot like managing virtual machine images that have development tools installed.  That's a system administration task in support of development, but not itself a development task.  Really no different from running backups on a development workstation.  Since it's probably not centrally controlled via group policy/whatever, it would be single-machine system administration, which belongs on Super User.  Or have I totally misunderstood the task?

Comment: @BenVoigt They're containers rather than full-fledged virtual machines, and aspects of Docker could be on topic at several sites, including SF. The "best" place for the question really is going to be dictated by the question itself and the sorts of answers you're looking for. For what the example question asked, I would think Programmers would be the best bet, rather than SU, which would focus more on _how_ to do something rather than _why_ or _best practice_.

Comment: I also think you misunderstood that question.  Seems like you thought it was about debugging Docker... but when I read it, it sounds like using Docker to move debug version of applications from computer A to computer B, and maybe about getting debug data like log files back from the containers.

Comment: @BenVoigt He's got multiple questions, and all of them seem to indicate he's unfamiliar with Docker and its best practices. They're all good questions and in need of good answers, but they're not really _ops_ questions.

Answer (score 10):

The OP is doing stuff as a developer on their laptop, that makes it not topical for Server Fault.

From the Server Fault about/faq/tour (whatever is's called this week)

> Don't ask about...
>   **Anything in a home or development environment**

For reason's unknown this part of the same page on StackOverflow is ignored, or determined to not include FOSS tool.

Ask about...

> Software development tools

In this, and many other cases, the tools are being used for software development, they are no different than any other software development tools.

Questions regarding them in these circumstances should have a home on StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting the relevant section of SO's guidelines.  I agree that it seems that these sorts of questions tend to be pushed off to other sites which is part of my reason for asking the community's opinion.  One thing that I think is adding more to the complexity is that "software development tools" is a category that is starting to expand from IDEs and compilers to CI/CD tools, management technologies like Docker, etc, that bridge more into traditional operations roles.  Thus the line blurs even more.  I suppose this is one reason for the proposed Area51 site.

Comment: @phoebus To be honest I used to think that there was no reason to have a separate devops site. These days I'm more in favour as then most of the truly crappy questions that SF gets would have a better home.

Comment: Being used for software development does not make something a software development tool.  Documenting code is a development activity; however questions about changing the font size in Word are not magically suitable for SO just because it's being done for a software README file.  Questions about developing Word plugins, or using a Word plugin that has features specifically for code such as UML diagram generation, could be on-topic.  Similarly VMware isn't on-topic on SO, except for stuff related to the VMware remote debug bridge.

Comment: @BenVoigt Shrugs - they ain't topical on SF either, that's why we close them.

Comment: Yeah, OS configuration on developer machines tends not to be so cookie-cutter... so SuperUser is the place for it.