# Should Docker questions go on Stack Overflow, Server Fault, or Super User?

Tags: discussion, scope

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26856042/do-i-want-a-container-handling-multiple-requests) has been flagged as off-topic for Stack Overflow, but a truckload of similar Docker-based questions go on Stack Overflow every day, that are not flagged. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26861550/ssh-into-a-docker-container-from-another-container-on-a-different-host), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26832604/how-to-implement-cpu-memory-docker-container-restrictions-on-gce-mysql-backu).

*[Topicality of "DevOps" Questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271279/topicality-of-devops-questions)* is about another Docker question, sounding similar to the above, that got flagged off Server Fault, and the answers there are quite clear that if the questioner is not an "ops person" then they shouldn't ask on Server Fault. So where do they go?

Comment: I would say it is a tool used by developers and therefor on-topic on SO.

Comment: OP opened a question as well: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276629/poor-conduct-of-high-reputation-user-and-abuses-that-follow

Comment: Developers end up interacting with docker directly and in the case of Dockerfiles, produce lines of code that are committed to a repository somewhere.  Hopefully that justifies my thinking beyond bias that it's perfectly fine to ask these kinds of questions on SO.

Comment: Your title question, "should docker questions go on SO or SF", is akin to asking "should computer questions go on SO or SF".

Comment: SO has a tag 'docker' but does not have the tag 'computer'.  So some people recognize there is a difference

Comment: Oh well, that was just the common-parlance "computer", meaning "everything that involves a computer somehow". I meant, on the one hand it's a tool that may be in the need of administration. On the other hand, it's a tool that can be used by developers. To me it sounds too general. A question on how to solve serious g++ dependency problems e.g. should imho go to Server-Fault, because it's administrative, and not a programming problem. Argh, I should write an answer when I find time ... -- edit: Michael Hampton says what I mean :P

Comment: kinda irritated about someone who insisted i move a Terraform question from here over to superuser. Which has 0 tags for terraform. Put it on Servefault with has 1 question tagged terraform. Here on SO there are more. now my question will languish unanswered.

Comment: @the0ther Bizarre. The HashiCorp tools are on topic here, and off-topic on SU, pretty much by definition. For pretty much the same reason Docker makes no sense on SU. Weird anyone would even think to move a question on such an obvious professional ops tool over there...

Comment: A couple of things to remember: Docker is just a lightweight VM, like a Debian QEMU/Chroot. The questions I've seen are mostly equivalent to questions about VMware or VirtualBox. There's nothing interesting about it from the programming or development perspective. Its a tool that's used on occasion by some developers. It does not elevate to *"tools primarily used for [programming and development]"*, and it does not rise to *" [a tool] unique to software development"*.

Comment: @jww why just don't put your comment as an answer? I need to downvote it, respectfully. "Docker is just a lightweight vm" and "is your favorite lightweight VM" are comments from a very little standview point. Are you flagging Git questions as well?

Comment: @Robert - Its yet another opinion in a sea of opinions. I've come to realize none of them are answer worthy; and the up/down votes don't matter. The only thing that matters is the site's policies and procedures. The up/down votes don't matter \[in practice\] because... As of today, there are 7284244 Stack Overflow users. Say 20% of them are high rep enough (with some reasonable definition of "enough rep"). Then you need SQUARE_ROOT(7284244 / 5) users to vote to to get to a minimum confidence interval. That's 1206.99958 users. A typical question looks like it gets 10 or 20 before it peters out.

Comment: @jww "Docker is just a lightweight VM" One of the reasons Docker gained so much traction was the software packaging and distribution that was built on it's management of OS containers. The use of containers like VM's is actively discouraged in their design. Maybe Vagrant is a closer example?
 I think labeling it "just a lightweight VM" is selling it a bit short. Things like Docker for Mac/Windows are dev tools. Dockers split into CE and EE kind of highlights their idea of the difference between Docker as a dev tool and Docker as a container service.

Comment: It just makes it difficult to divvy it up across so many sites.

Comment: Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46678488/unable-to-mount-existing-folder-in-docker-with-linux) dev environment setup question seems like it would be an SO question?

Comment: Given the increasing number of "How do I use docker" questions on SO, it may be worth reconsidering whether docker questions should go to Unix/Linux or Server Fault.

Answer (score 48):

*[Note: I'm a Server Fault moderator, and this post should be read in that light. In particular, I'm *not* a Stack Overflow moderator.]*

Welcome to topic overlap.

Since you've referred to one of my answers elsewhere on mSO, I guess I have to do some more clarifying.

First, the ways that Docker is used by developers and by system administrators *often differs*. It can be used by a developer or team to take code all the way from the developer's keyboard to production, with not much being required from IT beyond providing the bare metal (or even virtual machine) to run Docker on.

Thus, as sysadmins, we're usually more focused on making sure that Docker is installed and running properly, that there is enough disk space for containers and images, etc. Sysadmins don't usually do that much with your code, Dockerfiles, etc., though we may on occasion create base images.

This particular question is about the architecture of a deployed web application, which is a complete gray area. This is done by developers sometimes, by sysadmins sometimes. Ideally this in particular is something that sysadmins and developers should be collaborating on closely, in the true spirit of DevOps, as it requires both management of resources that sysadmins provide as well as designing and programming the application to take advantage of it.

Had the referenced question been asked on Server Fault originally, I would have just answered it. SF has had many similar questions, though they are often too broad and get into the realm of "design my app's infrastructure for me" which, if you ask me that, you'd better be writing a large check to go along with it. This one is specific enough to be answerable, and I do not quite understand the mass of downvotes that it collected.

---

As a general rule, I would say that *most* questions about Docker that a programmer is likely to come up with in the course of programming should be fine on Stack Overflow. Those that involve administering Docker itself in a production environment (not your workstation!) should be fine on Server Fault. When the question falls into a gray area such as the one referenced here, well, make your best guess and bring your hazmat suits.

Comment: It's a shame you focus on the first question since it's not a good example of what I am asking about; I just noted it was flagged.  Are "how do I ssh from A to B" questions on-topic for SO, just because the asker is a programmer?

Comment: Like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5906441/how-to-ssh-to-a-virtualbox-guest-externally-through-a-host) @Bryan? Also, have you read http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/why-cant-you-have-just-one-site/

Comment: @Bryan Personally I were going to ask "how do I ssh from A to B?" I'd go to [su]. But those questions are a bit more complicated than that.

Comment: What's the difference between administering Docker on a server or on a workstation? Would you accept programming-related question when they take place on a server?

Comment: [*Docker questions should also be welcome on Unix/Linux - especially those where the question is regarding unix behaviours*](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24794686#24794686) (copied from the Comms Room chat transcript, guidance provided by Jenny D.

Answer (score -4):

I feel that most Docker questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow. I don't know a better site, though.

My argument is that most question are related to administer or just use Docker. So they do not involve any programming. Just because it is a common tool for programmer, that makes non-programming question on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Programmers use web browsers and email client for their work, too. Still we would consider questions related to configuring email clients off-topic unless the problem itself is related to programming.

We should add this point of view also to the [docker] tag.

Comment: By this logic, _any_ deployment tool could be considered off topic. This is not comparable to web browsers and email clients, which everyone uses.

Comment: The point is: What are actually necessary for programming. A compiler, linker and so on: yes. Email client, Docker, desktop environment: no.

Comment: I don't think it was called out here before, but the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) says " if your question generally covers… software tools commonly used by programmers… then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"

Comment: @Bryan: Yeah, that's a good point. But it narrows it down whether Docker is a common tool or not. Email and web browser are common too...

Comment: @Bryan ".... **and** is a practical, answerable problem that is *unique to software development*", forgot to add

Comment: @usr1234567, git is not necessary for programming as well. With your logic, all the git questions should be on another site.

Comment: @Robert no, because there are git operations "unique to software development".

Comment: @Braiam, so when you version with Git a Dockerfile and a docker-compose.yml you're doing software development. I can bet that docker is a more software development thing than Git.

Comment: @Robert I'm not sure what you are getting of my comment. Both tools has functions and tasks that unless you are doing software development, you wouldn't touch it with a 9 foot pole.