# Should the Docker tag discourage "general support" questions?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

The docker tag was [recently updated](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15699487/7) with the text:

> GENERAL DOCKER SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com.

I'm not really sure what "general docker support" means. The top voted [answer on mSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/276642/596285) regarding the issue of where to ask these questions suggests that most questions about usage of developer tools are on topic for SO. And questions on how to manage docker as a systems administrator would go over to server fault.

Would it be appropriate to revert this edit to the tag wiki? If not, should the linked mSO question have an updated answer covering the new policy and also add a definition of what "general docker support" means in the wiki?

Comment: "most questions about usage of developer tools are on topic for SE" which is rubbish. That's why the scope is two pronged: a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development and one of the other three.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)

Comment: @paulcrovella, I agree, it's not clear to me either. Would others be comfortable with a warning banner on SO for all questions saying "general support questions are off topic"? It feels like it's discouraging on topic questions and ignoring the actual difference between the two sites.

Comment: @bjmyers, my question is about the proper contents of the tag wiki to match the policy identified in that question.

Comment: @BMitch I realized that after I flagged, and retracted my close vote.  I hadn't noticed that it left an auto-comment.

Comment: I can't make sense of this either. Docker is also a dev tool. It's a huge grey area to me. Most questions is from devs wanting to run their software in dev or prod. A lot of the issues people have are also due to poor workflows so you quickly also touch CI topics... and so much more. It's a mess and I don't know if it's even possible to change that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see that an [edit has been made to the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15699487/8), removing the problematic phrasing and being more accurate about what is on vs off topic:

> Docker supports both Linux and Windows containers. Questions about how Docker interacts with programming or programming with Docker containers is on-topic. General support questions for Docker the application may be off topic and better asked on https://superuser.com

This brings the tag back in line with the mSO policy, answering my question.