# Is it time to operate on the [DevOps]?

Tags: discussion, tags, questions, burninate-request

Do we really need a [devops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/devops) tag on Stack Overflow?
Putting the [topicality of those questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271279/2422776) aside for a moment, do we really gain anything from having such a tag?

While many of those questions are on-topic and do have merit, DevOps seems to be a meta tag at best. DevOps relates more to the process and the mindset used during development and less to the technologies themselves, which are the focus of Stack Overflow. If a question is about using technology X to do Y, do we really care if this is done as part of a DevOps process or by an ops person who doesn't even know any developers? Is there any value in grouping together questions about different technologies under a tag that's essentially related to an organizational workflow?

<sub>My apologies for the poorly constructed pun. If anyone has a better suggestion for a punny title, I'm all ears.</sub>

Comment: DevOps is moving towards the software development mindset - textual representations of pipelines, etc. And associated source control.

Comment: In most of the cases, this meta tag might be used as a synonym for CI/CD.

Comment: There might be support for this idea given the [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com) site...

Comment: Agreed, although I am wondering what the sponsored ad on that tag become, then?

Comment: Attempt #2 at a pun-y title: "DevOops". And yes, I know it's worse than the current title

Comment: Attempt #3 at a pun-y title: "Is it time to DelOps?"

Comment: The reason the DevOps tag exists is because it's a useful characterization.  How else are you going to do a search for questions related to DevOps?

Comment: @RobertHarvey why would you? How is that characterization useful in the context of SO?

Comment: @Mureinik: For the same reasons we have a [database] tag.  Perhaps we should be talking about removing that tag as well.  I'm sorry, but I just don't see the peril here.  If the argument is that the tag attracts off-topic questions, then make *that* argument.

Comment: Here is an example that the tag drives questions that are off-topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66175781/how-can-i-ask-a-remote-server-that-was-never-connected-with-my-local-machine-to

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I’m not sure how useful a tag can be when commenters have already offered up multiple different interpretations of the term "DevOps". Wikipedia includes no less than 7 different categories making up DevOps (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DevOps):

1. Coding – code development and review, source code management tools, code merging.
2. Building – continuous integration tools, build status.
3. Testing – continuous testing tools that provide quick and timely feedback on business risks.
4. Packaging – artifact repository, application pre-deployment staging.
5. Releasing – change management, release approvals, release automation.
6. Configuring – infrastructure configuration and management, infrastructure as code tools.
7. Monitoring – applications performance monitoring, end-user experience.

But even if you roll these categories up into just Dev and Ops, ask yourself this:

Is there a Dev or Development tag in Stack Overflow? No. That is far too broad of a tag to be useful.

Is there an Ops or Operations tag in Stack Overflow? No. Of course not.

So (rhetorical question coming) why would having a tag that encompasses both of these things make any sense?

Notes:

1. There is an [agile-development] tag in Stack Overflow (the Wikipedia article explains the connection to DevOps) but the guidance for that tag is clear:

QUESTIONS ABOUT SOFTWARE DEVELOPMENT METHODS AND PRACTICES OR PROJECT MANAGEMENT ARE OFF-TOPIC. Please consider Software Engineering or Project Management Stack Exchanges for these questions.

2. There actually is an [Operations] tag but in a different context, i.e., computational operations, which of course is appropriate for Stack Overflow.
3. Not the best pun in the world but I give you credit for trying.

Comment: Operations, in the sense of the Ops in DevSecOps/DevOps, has a full stack allocated to it...ServerFault.  That's the right stack for, "How do I keep this system running?" or, "How do I fix this broken system?" type questions.

Answer (score 13):

Let's move away from the buzzword "devops" and more think about "infrastructure as code", which is how many of these technologies bill themselves as.

Certain IaC technologies such as Jenkinsfiles and Pulumi use a real programming language (Groovy and TypeScript respectively), and may enjoy attention from those kinds of experts.

Other IaC technologies such as Ansible or Terraform use a markup language, and while documentation is bountiful, expertise is in reasonable demand.  I've found such expertise here myself and it has made my own Ansible scripts better for it.

When someone asks a question about either of these domains, it's less important to emphasize or consider their own expertise as either a programmer or non-programmer.  It's *mission critical* to emphasize the problem domain that they're in and solve it.

Stack Overflow doesn't typically care who you are or what level of expertise you have.  All it wants is an on-topic, concise and answerable question.  If questions about IaC can provide that, then there's no reason to dwell on the matter.  If one can't answer it, then *by design* one shouldn't attempt to, or they should forward it to someone who can.

I would not disagree with a circumstance that suggests that, if someone wants help debugging their servers, that would be out of scope here.  But if they had a narrow question about why their script wasn't copying a file, or how they could do text substitution in a variable, I don't see that as a problem.

Comment: I agree with this statement, but that wasn't the point I was trying to make. I'm completely fine with questions about Ansible or Terraform - my point was not to remove those questions, but the actual tag of "devops". If you're an Ansible or Terraform user, what do you gain by searching for questions under "devops" instead of directly under the relevant technology's tag?

Comment: I may have answered your question indirectly buy not defending the word "devops".  I think the tag could go, and I've provided some evidence for that justification.

Comment: So I think we're on the same page here - the tag can go, but the questions that exist under it are probably OK

Comment: Or more accurately - questions should be evaluated on their individual merit, and neither automatically be considered good or bad just because they have this tag

Comment: Another buzzword: "data scientist" means typically SQL digger in practice. A prediction: one or more buzzwords for the python/AI developers will soon appear.

Comment: Btw, I think "devops" is not so bad if we consider it as a synonym of "infrastructure as code". It has not corporate bullshitting taste, it is just an alternative abbreviation of IaC.

Comment: That feels like a real stretch to say "DevOps is a synonym for infrastructure-as-code".

Comment: @SteveBennett: I'm not talking about DevOps at all. I'm taking about infrastructure as code. I moved away from the buzzword.

Comment: I was not aware that the Institute for Advanced Architecture in Catalonia was so heavily invested in these technologies.

Comment: @peterh Oops, too late. "Data scientist" has already gotten co-opted to mean Python/AI developer...

Comment: Some Microsoft DevOps technologies use PowerShell as the scripting language.  It makes sense (to me) that if I were to ask a PowerShell question that dealt with DevOps issues, that I tag it with both `[PowerShell]` and `[DevOps]`.

Comment: @Flydog57:  No, PowerShell and whatever dev-ops technology that you have a question about.  Focusing on the technology rather than the practice is key.

Comment: The post starts with clear question: "Do we really need a devops tag on Stack Overflow?" Why not answer it directly: yes or no? This is Meta SO, not puzzling.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @sanyassh:  Because it's easy to get hung up on buzzwords and miss the forest for the trees.  I'm demonstrating that there's value in questions and technologies that fall in the devops camp such that we don't need the tag to express what they are.

Comment: My job title has DevOps in it.  The bulk of my work is configuration management orchestration with Ansible.  When I search for information to help with an issue, I search for Ansible, not DevOps.  I agree with the original post, that DevOps, or DevSecOps is more of a workflow concept, and less a technical topic.  I also agree that the work we do is best described as Infrastructure As Code in support of DevSecOps.  I say we don't need the tag here, as any question truly related to DevOps/DevSecOps is going to be better answered on a DevOps stack.